# process id ist different between getpid und Top command linux

Tags: linux, top-command

programm write current process id in file with function getpid() exemple 1100, but wenn command top run, i becomme process id 1101!!!!! why

Comment: Are you using fork() or similar calls in your program? Can we see your code?

Answer (score 1):

There are other, similar IDs that `top` can display, e.g., the thread ID or the process group ID.

Answer (score 0):

It is not at all possible. Both the getpid function output and the id displayed by top will be same. I hope you are confusing something.

Can you please briefly expain, how you are doing all these ?